# Advice on returning a single object in django

Tags: django

I am working on an online food ordering service and i have worked on most of the functionality. At the moment on request, i want the app to be able to return the menu of a given restaurant as requested by user. Am thinking the logic has something to do with the Primary Key but i don't know how to go about this.
Thank you in advance and have a blessed christmas..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the `get()` method to get a single object from the model if you know it's id (or primary key). Look at the documentation on how to [retrieve a single object with get](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#retrieving-a-single-object-with-get).

## For Example

```
#models.py

class Menu(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50)


#views.py

def get_menu(request, menu_id):
    menu = get_object_or_404(models.Menu, pk=menu_id)
    data = {'menu' : menu}
    return render_to_response('menu.html', data, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

#urls.py

url(r'^menu/(?P<menu_id>\d+)/$', 'yourappname.views.get_menu')
```

Comment: thanks but this function returns a TypeError, get_menu() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

Comment: in the url u need to define a url that sends a `menu_id` argument to the view. Check the updated answer above [look at the url part. Also, do not forget to change `yourappname` to your applications name.]

Comment: hey, thanks alot, but am coming across some funny error DoesNotExist No exception supplied,as i try to return a menu by its id in the url e.g http://127.0.0.1:8000/menu/3/. have any ideas

Comment: The `DoesNotExist` exception is raised as there is no menu with `id=3` in your database.

Comment: here are the views and models,

Comment: sori was supposed to put post code after tht...gimme a sec pliz

Comment: hey man...stackoverflow is complainin my code is to long but i think the reason am getting that exception is that the id of the item i was trying to call was created before i defined the above views. do you think that is the problem or am i just confusing myself

Comment: as i said, `DoesNotExist` exception is raised when an object queried does not really exist in the database. Just check if you actually have a Menu object with `id=3` in the database.

Comment: i do ..yes i did do check the database you know and i have an item with id=3, id=1

Comment: stackoverflow can complain all they want, here is the views    `def get_menu(request,category_id):
 menu= get_object_or_404(Category, pk=category_id)
 context={'menu':menu}
 return render(request, 'public/menu.html',context)
`

Comment: here is the models for the `Category app`,
`class Category(SmartModel):
 item=models.ManyToManyField(Item)
 title=models.CharField(max_length=64,help_text="Title of category e.g BreakFast")
 description=models.CharField(max_length=64,help_text="Describe the category e.g the items included in the category")
 #show_description=check box if description should be displayed
 #active=check box if category is still avialable
 display_order=models.IntegerField(default=0)
 owner= models.ForeignKey(Restaurant,help_text="Owners of menu")`

Comment: and here is how the category table looks like in the database, ` select * from menu_category_category
   ...> ;
1|1|1|2012-12-05 12:03:31.870775|1|2012-12-05 19:26:24.706798|Breakfast|Ham with bread|1|
2|1|1|2012-12-06 10:23:41.150043|1|2012-12-06 10:23:41.150248|Lunch|lunch|3|
3|1|1|2012-12-06 10:31:34.004257|1|2012-12-06 10:31:34.004528|Dinner|dinner|4|
`

Comment: ok, try this, launch the shell (`python manage.py shell`) inside shell do this 1.`from yourapp import models.Category` 2. `menu_3 = Category.objects.get(pk=3)` and 3. `menu_3`. Also it will be helpful if you paste the Exact error and traceback to http://dpaste.com/

Comment: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 373, in __repr__
    u = unicode(self)
  File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/f4l/menu_category/models.py", line 19, in __unicode__
    return "%s %s %s %s %s" % (self.item, self.title, self.description, self.display_order,self.owner)
  File "/home/mats-invasion/projects/f4l/env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/fields/related.py", line 343, in __get__
  raise self.field.rel.to.DoesNotExist`

Comment: sorry am not available most of the time but i am grateful...so what you think of the above...

Comment: hey buddy dont bother figuring that out, i did find the problem. in the 'menu_category.models' for the `owner` field i was using a `ForeignKey` instead of `ManyToMany` field. That chang fixed the problem

Comment: Thank you for your time and efforts friend.